# Populate jTable in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, sql-server-2005, jdbc, jtable

Why do I have these error? what does it mean? I only want to display all the data on my SQL DB.

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication25.SearchPatient.<init>(SearchPatient.java:26)
    at javaapplication25.SearchPatient$2.run(SearchPatient.java:146)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Here is the codes that I used, don't know how to fix it because I'm not good enough in programming a Java Apps. , can anyone help me here? :

```
package javaapplication25;

/**
 *
 * @author cleanfuel
 */
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class SearchPatient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SearchPatient
     */
    public SearchPatient() throws SQLException {
        initComponents();

        Statement stmt = null;

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Patients");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

        int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        Vector columns_vector = new Vector();
        Vector rows_vector = new Vector();

        for (int i=1; i< columns; i++){
        columns_vector.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
        }

        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_vector);

        while (rs.next()){

            rows_vector = new Vector();
            for (int j=1; j<columns; j++){

                rows_vector.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(rows_vector);
        }
        tblPatients.setModel(dtm);

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


Connection connection;
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        connection = Main.ConnectDatabase();
    }
```

Comment: `don't know how to fix it because I'm not good enough in programming a Java Apps.` So every time you have a little problem you are going to come here and ask us to solve it for you? Sorry, that is not the way it works. You need to learn how to solve problems on your own. The error is on line 26 and a variable is null. You should be able to figure out which variable is null on that line. All you have to do is add a System.out.println(...) for every variable used on the line. One of them will be null.

Comment: sorry sir camickr if I always asked question here...

Comment: @CrystalMaiden The strength of any good developer is there ability to research there own problems. There's nothing wrong with assign questions, but this shouldn't be the first place you start, that's all

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking questions. But the question should be: "A variable on line 26 is null and I don't know why". Learning to read a trace is basic if you want to do any kind of programming. Show us that you have made a little effort to try and understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these two lines, one after the other

```
Statement stmt = null;

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Patients");
```

You've not initialised the `stmt` object, so it `null`, nothing, natta

Basically, it's like trying to turn on the TV before you've plugged it in, it's not likely to work

Take a look at [JDBC Data Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details, but essentially, you need to establish a connection to a database and then use that connection to create the Statement object, then you can query it.

Comment: Oh! I see it's because I shortcut the connection in Window Opened Event... I will recode it sir MadProgrammer and tell you what will happen